# Difficulties In Migration from Spring 4 to Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-4

Planning to Migrate Spring 4 project to Spring 5.

I browsed about spring 5 features  and it has some interesting features like Webflux , Reactive Programming ... which may increase the performance of my application.

I am not Sure how difficulties will be to migrate.

Reg Project complexity:
1) More complex Project which has more APi exposed and Consumed.
2) Connected with Cassandra DB.
3) size of a project is little bit Big.

Any suggestions related to difficulties in migration will be much appreciated.

Comment: See: [Upgrading to Spring Framework 5.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to migrate form Spring 4 to 5 and start using features such as Spring Webflux, basically you'll have to rewrite most of your code.

You can either choose to keep on using the existing annotations or use [Router Functions](https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/22/new-in-spring-5-functional-web-framework) (which, in my opinion, are way too complex and don't give you too much flexibility compared to the traditional annotations approach).

You'll also have to change all your interfaces that return one object from `MyCustomClass` to `Mono<MyCustomClass>` and from `Collection<MyCustomClass>` to `Flux<MyCustomClass>`. Your DBs may not be relational, as all existing drivers are blocking. In order to get the maximum of WebFlux, you need to use [Reactive Databases.](https://spring.io/blog/2018/12/07/reactive-programming-and-relational-databases)

Generally speaking, you'd be better off rewriting your application than migrating to WebFlux.

Do you really need to migrate? Are you running into perfomance issues? You may consider creating new applications in WebFlux if the current ones are not facing any issues.

Take a look into this [article](https://spring.io/blog/2018/06/20/the-road-to-reactive-spring-cloud) by Josh Long. Maybe you don't really need WebFlux at all.

I am a big fan of Spring in general, but working with WebFlux is not easy and there will be some steep learning curve.